# Why does the EdDSA use a 2b-bit hash function?

Tags: eddsa

The [EdDSA signature](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf#page=6) of a message $M$ under key $k$ is created as:

1. Define $r=H(h_b,....,h_{2b−1},M)\in\{0,1,...,2^{2b}−1\}$.
2. Define $R=rB$.
3. Define $S=(r+H(\underline R,\underline A,M)s)\bmod\ell$.

Output $(\underline R,\underline S)$ as signature (where $\underline S$ is the $b$-bit little-endian encoding of $S$).

My question is: why does it use of $2b$-bit hash function? What will happen if we use of $b$-bit hash function in the above equations? The $r$ in 1 has $2b$-bit, but it computes the $R=rB$ in 2 and $S$ in 3 at the $\ell$ module. Note that $\ell$ has $b$-bit. Why don't we use the hash function with $b$-bit output? Is there any security problem with this?

Comment: Did you check the size of the group? In ECC $R = [ r\bmod \text{order of the group}]B$ so greater has no effect. If you see $b$, then you reduce the security to half bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does EdDSA use of $2b$-bit hash function?

It insures $r\bmod\ell$ is almost uniformly distributed in $\{0,1,\ldots\ell-1\}$. That's explained at the [end](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf#page=9) of the section on *Pseudorandom generation of $r$*, which also explains $H$ of $b+61$-bit would be enough for this purpose.

> Is there any security problem with this?

Update: <strike>I know no</strike> I'm told ***there's is actually*** a [purely cryptographic attack](https://blog.cr.yp.to/20191024-eddsa.html) if we reduce $H$ to $b$-bit. It

> leaks the private key to lattice or FFT algorithms on relatively small numbers of signatures, with Howgrave–Graham/Smart or Bleichenbacher. The setting is very weak: you just need to get a decently large number of signatures on distinct messages, not even chosen messages, and—*bam*—the private key falls out. In the Minerva attack, there was a separate side channel giving additional information about the per-signature secrets even if they were uniformly distributed; this enabled the adversary to do rejection sampling to give a nonuniform distribution for the lattice attack.  With b-bit secrets reduced modulo the curve order, the distribution is already nonuniform enough for the lattice attack.

Turns out that a less-than-uniform modulo $\ell$ not only invalidate the security argument, it allows an attack! It also (and more badly) affects ECDSA, and there was precedents as explained [earlier](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf#page=8) in the section on *Pseudorandom generation of $r$* of Bernstein's paper.